# Palindrome Using Stack Data Structure

Tags: python

Problem:

Write a Python program that takes user input of a word and determines if it is a Palindrome or not using the Stack data structure.

A palindrome is a word that can be read the same backward as forward. Some examples of palindromic words are noon, civic, radar, level, rotor, kayak, reviver, racecar, redder, madam, and refer.

The following code is what I've done so far and need help to make it compile correctly:

```
import Stack

def palidromeChecker(words):
palidromestack = Stack.Stack()

words = user_input("Type a word: ")
for x in words:
 palidromestack.push(x)
palindrome = True
for x in words:
 if x != palidromestack.top():
    palindrome = False
break
palidromestack.pop()
if palindrome:
print (words, "is a palindrome")
else:
print (words, "is not a palindrome")
```

Comment: `import Stack`!! Where did you get that module from? can you also mention the error you are receiving ?

Comment: @Unni I am using python 3.6 and was told you to use import Stack when creating a stack.  Hence the palidromestack = Stack.Stack() declaration.

Comment: `Stack` is not a stdlib module. Where did you get it?

Comment: As far as I know, you can use `list` as a stack. I don't see a `Stack` module in Python 3 docs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Comment: The closest thing I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413735/trying-to-stop-an-error-with-stacks-in-python). Is the same `Stack` module what we're looking at here?

Answer (score 1):

No one seems clear on what a `Stack` is, so let me show you how you might do this with a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque)

```
import collections

def palindrome_checker(word):
    # casefold the word, since "Racecar" is a palindrome just like "racecar"
    q = collections.deque(word.casefold())
    while True:
        try:
            l, r = q.popleft(), q.popright()
        except IndexError:
            # we've reached the end without error!
            return True
        else:
            if l != r:
                return False
```

That said the canonical palindrome checker in python is just:

```
def palindrome_checker(word):
    word = word.casefold()  # as before
    return word == word[::-1]
```

Slicing a string with `[::-1]` says "Give me back this string, unbounded on each end, in reverse order." This is equivalent to `str(reversed(word))`

Comment: as it happens, this is the rare case where it's about as short in Haskell as it is in Python. `isPalindrome s' = let s = map toLower s' in s == reverse s` (with `toLower` imported from Data.Char)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the stack confusion

I changed the code to the following and it seems to be working:

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self):
    self.items=[]

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items==[]

def push(self,data):
    self.items.append(data)

def size(self):
    return len(Self.items)

def show(self):
    print (self.items)

def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

def pop(self):
    assert not self.isEmpty()
    return self.items.pop()

word=input("Enter a word: ")
s=Stack();

for i in word:
 s.push(i)

list1 = ""
while not s.isEmpty():
 list1 += s.pop()

if(list1 == word):
print(word,"is a palindrome");
else:
print(word,"is not a palindrome");
```